# computing the coordinates of vertices of convex regular polyhedra and 4-polytopes

Tags: euclidean-geometry, combinatorial-geometry, convex-geometry, platonic-solids

I am considering what I understand to be generalizations of the platonic solids. In the plane one can easily obtain the vertices of a convex regular k-gon by computing roots of unity, and this can be done for k any integer number of vertices.
In 3-space the task is more arduous and appears to require a little creativity, although instead of infinitely many convex regular polygons we need only consider the five Platonic solids (tetrahedron, cube, octohedron, dodacahedron, and icosahedron). In 4 dimensions we have 6 sets of vertices to compute (4-simplex, 4-cube, 4-orthoplex, 24-cell, 120-cell, and the 600-cell), and in higher dimensions there are only the n-simplex, n-cube, and n-orthoplex, which all seem fairly straight forward (I may be mistaken).
I believe it is the case that any convex regular polytope will have vertices on the unit n-sphere, but what those locations might be are a mystery to me. What general method does one use to compute the location of the vertices of these polyhedra/polytopes?

Comment: I'm not sure how they were calculated, but http://www.eusebeia.dyndns.org/4d/regular gives coordinates for all 6 of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some years ago I have written [Haskell source code](https://code.mathr.co.uk/reflex/blob/6864885fb45dee27dc417fd790b53607eaa287d7:/Polychoron.hs) (which may have bitrotted by now) for numerically calculating the symmetry group (in terms of $4 \times 4$ matrices) of 4D polytopes starting from their [Schläfli symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schl%C3%A4fli_symbol).  The reference I used to implement it is the Schläfli determinant in [HSM Coxeter's Regular Polytopes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Polytopes_(book)), but unfortunately I no longer have a copy to hand for a more precise citation.  I believe the determinant method works for arbitrary dimension, though I only tried it in 3D and 4D.

Once you have the symmetry matrices you can apply them all in turn to a vector to get a set of coordinates, depending which vector you choose you can construct variously truncated polytopes.  I wrote a [blog post](https://mathr.co.uk/blog/2009-10-15_reflex_preview.html) in 2009 about it, but it's quite light on detail (though it does have a video).